# js onbeforeunload I want to submit the form after page refresh or close, but failed

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I want to submit my form data to database when user refresh or close the window.
I tried this, but it didn't work. The p demo1 will change to No when refresh or close. But will change to Yes after refresh or close. But the sumbit part is not trigger.
I tried this two method, both of them didn't work
document.getElementById("all_questions").submit();
$('#save').click();
It can work if I click the submit button, use Django as framework

```html
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="No";
    document.getElementById("all_questions").submit();
    $('#save').click();
  }
</script>

<form method = "POST"  name = "answer_question" id="all_questions">
<p id="demo1">Yes</p>
data
<div class="save-item1"><button class="save-button" type="submit" id="save" name="Complete">Save</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are calling events which are not captured by window object yet.

Comment: Hi, sorry What do you mean by calling events which are not captured by window object? Could you give me a example? you mean I submit the form before the window close? Could you give a solution on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot call events like submit() and click() or any event without registering those events with the element.

Comment: How can I register those events with the element? Could you give me a example? I wanna when the user close or refresh the window, the form can be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form reliably on page refresh or close can be challenging due to the asynchronous nature of the `onbeforeunload` event.

use the `navigator.sendBeacon` method, which is designed for sending data in the background, even during page unload

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "No";

        // Serialize form data
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("all_questions"));
        var data = new URLSearchParams(formData);

        // Send data using navigator.sendBeacon
        navigator.sendBeacon("/your-submit-endpoint", data);
    });

    // If you also want to handle form submission on button click
    document.getElementById("all_questions").addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "No";

        // Serialize form data
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var data = new URLSearchParams(formData);

        // Send data using navigator.sendBeacon
        navigator.sendBeacon("/your-submit-endpoint", data);
        
        // Optionally, you can redirect or perform other actions after form submission
    });
</script>

<form method="POST" name="answer_question" id="all_questions">
    <p id="demo1">Yes</p>
    data
    <div class="save-item1"><button class="save-button" type="submit" id="save" name="Complete">Save</button></div>
</form>
```